# How to read Protobuf oneof message using C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Consider a simple Protobuf code like this:

```
message MessageName
{
  oneof some_options {
    OptionA optionAName = 1;
    OptionB optionBName = 2;
  }
}
```

This will generate the following C++ code (or something like it, I've renamed some variables manually so it may not be 100% right):

```
typedef struct _namespace_name_MessageName {
    pb_size_t which_some_options;
    union {
        namespace_name_OptionA optionAName;
        namespace_name_OptionB optionBName;
    } some_options;
} namespace_name_MessageName;
```

**How do I read this message in C++?** I would like to say "if it is OptionA, do this" and "if it is OptionB, do this". I haven't been able to find out how `which_some_options` works though, I can't find it in the documentation at all. I did read [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#oneof-embedded-message-fields) but I can't find any of the methods mentioned there in the code that Protobuf generated. An example that shows how I should accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not the code produced by Google `protoc` compiler. It seems you are using [Nanopb](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/reference.html) (I'm just guessing as this is the first result when searching for `pb_size_t`). In this case, reading `protoc` documentation won't help much, obviously.

Comment: Per [documentation](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/concepts.html#oneof), `which_some_options` would hold the tag of the active message, here 1 or 2 (tags are integers after the `=` sign in the proto definition). `Nanopb` also generates named constants for those tags.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem in my project.

My solution worked normaly.

I am using proto3.

```
struct OptionA 
{
  int x1;
  int x2;
  string x3;
};

struct OptionB 
{
  int y1;
  int y2;
  string y3;
};
```

Sending side:

```
message MessageName
{
  enum option_type {TYPE_A, TYPE_B}

  oneof some_options {
      OptionA optionAName = 1;
      OptionB optionBName = 2;
  }
}
```

Receiving side:

```
if MessageName.option_type == TYPE_A
    OptionA *ptrA = MessageName.optionAName()

if MessageName.option_type == TYPE_B
    OptionB *ptrB = MessageName.optionBName()
```